# How can I Import multiple excel files with several sheets?

Tags: r, excel, function, google-sheets, import

Good nights everyone:

I am trying to import 8 excel files with the same structure but with different names. I have the code to import one file with the first 3 sheets, but i have to repeat this code 8 times. I would like to create a function to put it only one time and also I need to know where are they from (the name of excel file). Thank you in advance.

```
library(readxl)
read_excel_allsheets <- function("path", tibble = false){
sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets("path")
sheets <- sheets[c(1,2,3)]
x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel("path", sheet = X,skip = 5))
if(!tibble) x <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
names(x) <- sheets
x
all_data1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sheets, function(X) 
transform(readxl::read_excel("path", sheet = X,skip = 5), estatus = X,tipo="Corriente",enfoque="Sector")))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
read_excel_allsheets <- function(path, tibble = FALSE) {
      sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(path)
      sheets <- sheets[c(1,2,3)]
      x <- do.call(rbind, lapply(sheets, function(X) 
              transform(readxl::read_excel(path, sheet = X,skip = 5), 
                               estatus = X,tipo="Corriente",enfoque="Sector")))
      if(!tibble) x <- lapply(x, as.data.frame)
      names(x) <- sheets
      return(x)
}

all_data <- lapply(list.files('/path', full.names = TRUE), read_excel_allsheets)
```

Comment: Excuse me. I do not understand. I have 8 excel files in this path:/Users/ladyinfante/Documents/oficina/Control de calidad/CCNN. Do I have to put this here: all_data <- lapply(list.files('/Users/ladyinfante/Documents/oficina/Control de calidad/CCNN', full.names = TRUE), read_excel_allsheets). I am trying but I have a mistake.

Comment: Excuse me. Im trying to understand. How do I have to put the path? in this folder: /Users/ladyinfante/Documents/oficina/Control de calidad/CCNN/test1.xlsx /Users/ladyinfante/Documents/oficina/Control de calidad/CCNN/test3.xlsx and so far until test8. thank you

Comment: @LadyInfante what is the output of `list.files('/Users/ladyinfante/Documents/oficina/Control de calidad/CCNN', full.names = TRUE)` ? A list of excel files? and all of these excel file have multiple sheets in them?

Comment: You did not answer the questions which I asked.

Comment: I have 8 workfiles excel each one 4 sheets. there are 32 sheets in total. I need to put in a data frame together. I am copying this code 8 times and it works, but that's not efficient. Thank you.

Comment: So this does give you those 8 files, right? `list.files('/Users/ladyinfante/Documents/oficina/Control de calidad/CCNN/', full.names = TRUE)` ? If yes, then use `all_data <- lapply(list.files('/Users/ladyinfante/Documents/oficina/Control de calidad/CCNN/', full.names = TRUE), read_excel_allsheets)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212043/discussion-between-lady-infante-and-ronak-shah).

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

read_excel_allsheets <- function(path, tibble = FALSE) {
      sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(path)
      sheets <- sheets[c(1,2,3)]
      x <- map_dfr(sheets,  ~ .x %>%
              mutate(readxl::read_excel(path, sheet = .x,skip = 5), 
                    estatus = .x,tipo="Corriente",enfoque="Sector")))
      if(!tibble) x <- map(x, as.data.frame)
      names(x) <- sheets
      x
}

all_data <- map(list.files('/path', full.names = TRUE), read_excel_allsheets)
```